# Why can I invoke == with a defaulted <=> but not a user-provided one?

Tags: c++, comparison, standards, c++20, spaceship-operator

```
#include <compare>

struct A
{
    int n;
    auto operator <=>(const A&) const noexcept = default;
};

struct B
{
    int n;
    auto operator <=>(const B& rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return n <=> rhs.n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A{} == A{}; // ok
    B{} == B{}; // error: invalid operands to binary expression
}
```

compiled with clang-10 as `clang -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp`

Why does `A{} == A{}` work but not `B{} == B{}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the original design of the spaceship operator, `==` is allowed to call `<=>`, but this is later disallowed due to efficiency concerns (`<=>` is generally an inefficient way to implement `==`).  `operator<=>() = default` is still defined to implicitly define `operator==`, which correctly calls `==` instead of `<=>` on members, for convenience.  So what you want is this:

```
struct A {
    int n;
    auto operator<=>(const A& rhs) const noexcept = default;
};

// ^^^ basically expands to vvv

struct B {
    int n;
    bool operator==(const B& rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return n == rhs.n;
    }
    auto operator<=>(const B& rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return n <=> rhs.n;
    }
};
```

Note that you can independently default `operator==` while still providing a user-defined `operator<=>`:

```
struct B {
    int n;
    // note: return type for defaulted equality comparison operator
    //       must be 'bool', not 'auto'
    bool operator==(const B& rhs) const noexcept = default;
    auto operator<=>(const B& rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return n <=> rhs.n;
    }
};
```

Comment: @xmllmx [\[over.match.oper\]/3.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4) (note that the rewritten candidate set of `==` doesn't include `<=>`)

Comment: *operator<=>() = default is still defined to implicitly define operator==*, could you refer me to the page of the standard on this statement?

Comment: @xmllmx [class.compare.default/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#compare.default-5)